# lightning-record-edit-form not rendering anything when running via another profile

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-recordeditform

I have created a flow.

Where I have a profile check that of profile is "Retention" then show an LWC screen.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Task_Detail__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Issue_Category__c" disabled="true" value={issueCategory}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Logistics_Type__c" disabled="true" value={logisticsType}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Issue_Type_Sub_Type__c" value={issueType} onchange={handleChangeOfIssueType}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Issue_Sub_Type__c" value={issueSubType} onchange={handleChangeOfIssueSubType}></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Metadata:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="issueCategory" type="String" label="Issue Category Value" role="inputOnly"/>
        <property name="logisticsType" type="String" label="Logistics Type Value" role="inputOnly"/>
        <property name="issueType" type="String" label="Issue Type Value"/>
        <property name="issueSubType" type="String" label="Issue Sub Type Value"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

In debug the LWC shows up when I run with retention profile user, but when I execute this flow from a real scenario for retention profile, the screen shows nothing. Just a blank with "Next" button.

I have even kept this to check if the values come in the UI, `<div>Hi I was here {issueCategory}</div>` and issueCatergory is getting printed fine.

I think the primary reason might be that `Retention` profile does not have edit access to `Task_Detail__c` record, that is why the `lightning-record-edit-form` does not show anything as it tries to create a record with `Task_Detail__c` adn this profile does mnot have create access, but I have made the flow run as `Runs as System`, so this should actually not affect this, Right?
Any thing else which I can do to make `lightning-record-edit-form` work without giving create access from Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Which Context Do Flows Run In](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) shows that the context for Flows only apply to certain flow elements

> Context impacts what the following flow elements can do with
> Salesforce data:
>
> - Action
> - Create Records
> - Delete Records
> - Get Records
> - Subflow
> - Update Records

Since this is a custom LWC within a screen flow, setting the flow context as `System Context Without Sharing` *won't have any affect* on your custom component. Which means, that [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation):

> This component also takes care of field-level security and sharing
> for you, so users see only the data they have access to

won't display your object/record for the reason you noted: the profile does not have actual create/edit access to the object.

To accomplish what you're looking to do, you'd have to leverage a flow screen (with relevant field types to input) and then map those inputs to the relevant fields in a `Create Record` / `Update Record` flow element that will respect your flow's running context.

Comment: I just built a custom lwc component with custom comboxes. Taking the values from apex and used flowevent to update variables in flows. Cannot go with flow screen as there is some more than 3 level dependent picklist which needs to be shown.